# minitest test rescue block for Resque::TermException

Tags: ruby, exception, resque, minitest, rescue

I am writing tests with minitest for a resque worker.

How do I write a test for the rescue block that gets called in case Resque gets terminated and sends a Resque::TermException to the worker?

My approach is to stub one of the methods called by the worker and have it raise a Resque::TermException instead.

Sometimes I can raise the exception, but it happens at the wrong time and kills the testrun. And now I tried something like this:
(I'm using fixtures and mocha)

```
test "if interrupted it removes the file" do
  CSV.stub(:open).and_raise(Resque::TermException.new(15))

  report = Report.find_by_id(1)
  Report.expects(:find_by_id).returns(report)

  ReportJob.perform({ 'test' => 'test' })
  refute File.exist? ReportJob.report_file(report)
end
```

but no luck running it:

```
1) Error:
ReportTest#test_if_interrupted_it_removes_file:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
test/resque-tasks/spreadsheet_report_test.rb:2:in `block in <class:ReportTest>'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/testcase.rb:17:in `run'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:36:in `block in run'
...
```

Comment: What's you question?

Comment: His question is "How do I write a test for the rescue block that gets called in case Resque gets terminated and sends a Resque::TermException to the worker?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocha currently uses this syntax for stubs and raises:

```
object.stubs(:expected_method).raises(Exception, 'message')
```

See http://www.rubydoc.info/github/floehopper/mocha/Mocha/Expectation:raises

Are you perhaps using an older version of Mocha, with a different syntax?

Or is it possible you're accidentially using RSpec syntax?

Comment: Thanks - yes, I had 2 errors in my code: `stub` instead of `stubs` and `and_raises` instead of `raises`, now it works beautifully and raises the Resque::TermException within the test without terminating the tests :)